# Ruler below chapter heading

Tags: sectioning, chapters, rules

I am writing my thesis work using Lyx. Could anyone please help me with the code for positioning a ruler below the chapter title? The code I have doesn't display any ruler below the chapter title.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setheight{\headrule}{15pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{ %
\fancyhf{} % remove everything
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2.5pt} % remove lines as well
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}
```

Comment: Wellcome to TeX SX! Please provide a Minimal Working Example (MWE). It is easier for people to run your document and help you.

Comment: It might be worth looking to see if you school provides a thesis template (or if someone has one). This is really your best bet for meeting the often "silly" requirements that are imposed on theses.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package, which shows several example usages.

Comment: The memoir package is very flexible and has a lot of fancy chapter heading styles. Others are to be found in the MemoirChapStyle.pdf file (search for it in CTAN).